# Select characters for "OperatorSubstitution"

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, customization, fonts

The details section of the documentation for [`PrivateFontOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrivateFontOptions.html) states that:

> - With the default setting `"OperatorSubstitution" -> True`, special characters such as `{`, `(`, or `[` are replaced by the equivalent characters in a special Wolfram System font. This allows, for example, spanning characters to change size when the expression containing them grows larger.
> - With the setting `"OperatorSubstitution" -> False`, such characters are not replaced by equivalent Wolfram Language characters. In this case, spanning characters cannot change size automatically.

Is there a way to tell Mathematica to substitute only certain characters? Particularly, I would like to get automatically size-changing spanning characters, but keep other characters (such as `@`, `$` and `#`) unchanged.